# Problem involving cross products

Tags: geometry, linear-algebra

I have a problem in vector algebra.
In this [Wolfram-page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html) the last two formulas (9) and (10) are:
$$
\frac{ | (x_2 - x_1) \times (x_1 - x_0) | }{|x_2 - x_1 |} = 
\frac{ | (x_0 - x_1) \times (x_0 - x_2) | }{|x_2 - x_1 |}
$$
I've tried to apply properties founded in this other [Wolfram-crossproduct-page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CrossProduct.html) but I still don't understand it. How is possible? And why the do this vectors manipulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{align}|(x_2-x_1)\times(x_1-x_0)|&=|(x_1-x_2)\times(x_0-x_1)|\\&=|(x_0-x_1)\times(x_1-x_2)|\\&=|(x_0-x_1)\times((x_0-x_1)+(x_1-x_2))|\\&=|(x_0-x_1)\times(x_0-x_2)|\end{align}$

where the second is because you are in magnitude signs and the third is because the cross product of a vector with itself (or any parallel vector) is zero.

Comment: absolute value?? i thought the $|v \times w|$ was the magnitude of the cross product between v and w is magnitude not absolute value..

Comment: You are right it is magnitude, but the magnitude is always positive.  I should have said it that way and will fix.  I just wanted to justify that changing the order of the factors did not change the result, whereas for the cross product itself it changes the sign.

Comment: ok now it's more clear. but the remaining question is.. why they do that manipulation?

Comment: @nkint: Just to give you more options for using the result, I think.